# Как узнать, есть ли элемент в массиве

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как узнать, есть ли элемент в массиве, но без учета типа данных, т.е. если в массиве есть `[(int)1]`, то поиск `(string)"1"` вернет `true`?

Answer (score 4):

```js
var test = [1, 2, 3];
function hasValue(arr, value) {
  return arr.findIndex(item => item == value) != -1;
}
console.log(hasValue(test, "2")? "found" : "not found");
```

Comment: Логичнее бы `arr.some` использовать

Answer (score 1):

Если я все правильно понял, то метод Array.includes(item) работает именно так, как тебе нужно, только вопрос в том, какие именно типы у тебя там могут быть, если только строки и числа, тогда:

```
var mixedArray = [1,'2',3]
function hasElement(arr, element) {
  return arr.includes(String(element)) // или Number(element), но лучше приводить к строке
}

hasElement(mixedArray, 2) //true
hasElement(mixedArray, '2') //true
```