# Как проверить переменную на вхождение в массив

Tags: javascript

Есть массив, который приходит с сервера:

`testRepliesTypes = ["button", "button","option"];`

И есть массив допустимых значений:

`var testPossibleReplies = ["button", "option"];`

```
for (i = 0; i < testRepliesTypes.length; i ++){
tests["ava reply types are OK"] = testPossibleReplies.indexOf(testRepliesTypes[i]) > 0;
}
```

Такая проверка работает, только если в массиве допустимых значений порядок значений такой, как выше. Если поменять местами `"button" и "option"`, проверка не работает.

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Так что надо-то? определить наличие в массиве с сервера токенов, отсутствующих в допустимых значениях? проверить, что в массиве с сервера каждый токен присутствует хотя бы один раз? посчитать количество недопустимых токенов? допустимых токенов? что-то ещё? В общем - какого ответа Вы ожидаете?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как узнать, есть ли элемент в массиве](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/805689/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5)

Comment: Проверить, что каждый элемент массива с сервера входит в допустимые значения

Comment: Замените  `> 0;` на  `> -1;`